# Unable to Route to ASP.NET Core Login Page from Angular UI

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, abp

I am experiencing an issue while trying to navigate to the URL https://www.xxx.com.tr/account/login from my Angular UI. When I enter the URL directly into the browser's address bar, it successfully opens the default login page (cshtml). However, when I attempt to route from the Angular UI, it doesn't work as expected.

Below are the relevant configurations I have:

```
  ...
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.account').then(m => m.AccountModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'identity',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.identity').then(m => m.IdentityModule.forLazy()),
  }...
```

ASP.NET Core Endpoint Configuration:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        // Fallback
        endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");
    });
```

Navbar Routing Attempt:

```
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
              <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="logout()" >
                Logout
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" routerLink="/account/login" >
                Login
              </a>
            </ul>
```

I'm wondering if there's a specific configuration or step I might be missing to properly route to the ASP.NET Core login page from the Angular UI. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!